# Can we use WebSocket sink, in Spring cloud stream app starters, as WebSocket source?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Can I use the WebSocket sink available in **Spring Cloud Stream App Starters** as WebSocket Source. So that when I start the source the clients can send messages to the source as there is a websocket server listening on a specific port.

Answer (score 1):

The existing sink for `websocket` won't work as a source out of the box. The sink receives the data from a middleware and send that to the sink. In the case of a source, its the other way around, i.e it receives messages from a `websocket` endpoint and sends that to the middleware. The option at this point is to provide a custom `websocket` source from your side until a formal `websocket-source` is available. If you go with this route, please consider contributing that back to `spring-cloud-stream-app-starters`. Spring Integration has excellent coverage for [web sockets](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/web-sockets.html). You can use that as a starter.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have any documents on how to create a spring-cloud-stream-app-starter source ? Will be helpful.

Comment: See [this from the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Celsius.RC1/reference/html/_introduction.html#_creating_new_stream_application_starters_and_generating_artifacts) for some ideas: